# More than one row returned by a subquery and help on logic formulating

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables: `event table`, `down_event table`, `dummy table`

In the `event table` it contains the column `terminal_id`,`event_start_adj`,`event_end_adj` and `event_duration_sec` see picture below:
[image: event table]

Now in the `down_event table`, it contains the column `id`, `terminal_id`, `event_description`, `down_date`, `down_time`, `down_duration_sec`. See picture below:

[image: down_event table]

Lastly, the 3rd table is the `dummy table` which contains columns: `terminal_id`, `availability_date`, `availability_time`, `duration_sec`. See picture below:

[image: dummy table]

In the `dummy table` the `duration_sec` has a default value of **3600** while the `availability_time` intervals from **00:00:00** up to **23:00:00**. The `availability_date` is the one that sorts all the date when the event happened in the down_event table.

The problem is i need to subtract the `down_duration_sec` from the default value of the `duration_sec` of the `dummy table` and **update** it. So if the `down_duration_sec` for example is 1 second then it will be 3600 - 1 = 3599. Then if that event occurred at **03:04:44** (found in the `event table` and `down_event table`) it will fall on the **03:00:00** on the dummy table. Then the `event_duration_mins` that is on the `event table` that has a value of **42** will be added on the **03:00:00** updating it in the `dummy table` to **03:42:00** and the duration_sec to 3599 for the date of **2020-04-01**.

First I have tried updating the duration_sec with my query below:

```
UPDATE dashboard.dummy SET duration_sec = 3600 - (SELECT down_duration_sec FROM dashboard.down_event WHERE terminal_id IN (SELECT terminal_id FROM dashboard.dummy)) WHERE terminal_id IN (SELECT terminal_id FROM dashboard.down_event WHERE terminal_id IN (SELECT terminal_id FROM dashboard.dummy)) AND availability_date IN (SELECT down_date FROM dashboard.down_event WHERE down_date IN (SELECT availability_date FROM dashboard.dummy))
```

but the problem PostgreSQL threw an error of *ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression*. I need help on my query and what to do for the other columns in my `dummy` table that's why I explained everything. I'm planning to update it one by one but i think it will take a lot of time doing it. So if there is any idea that i can try i'll try it but for now i don't know why PostgreSQL is throwing that error to me. I it's because of the *=* sign in the *duration_sec =* but i've tried doing it as an *IN* but still won't work.

Edit:

Each `terminal_id` has different down_duration_sec on the `down_event_table`.

Please see screenshot below:
[image: duration-sec]

Comment: This error occurs because your subselect are returning more than 1 line. You need to aggregate the values or put a LIMIT 1 on the end of your subselect (not recommended).

Comment: But i need to update more than 1k data for these. The picture provided are for only 1 terminal. The actual data has more than 1k terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subquery return more then a row so you could try using  limit  1

```
UPDATE dashboard.dummy 
SET duration_sec = 3600 - (
    SELECT down_duration_sec 
    FROM dashboard.down_event 
    WHERE terminal_id IN (SELECT terminal_id FROM dashboard.dummy)
    LIMIT 1
) 
WHERE terminal_id IN (  
    SELECT terminal_id 
    FROM dashboard.down_event 
    WHERE terminal_id IN (SELECT terminal_id FROM dashboard.dummy)
) 
AND availability_date IN (
    SELECT down_date 
    FROM dashboard.down_event 
    WHERE down_date IN ( SELECT availability_date FROM dashboard.dummy)
)
```

OR use an aggreation function eg: min() or max() o avg()

```
UPDATE dashboard.dummy 
SET duration_sec = 3600 - (
    SELECT min(down_duration_sec) 
    FROM dashboard.down_event 
    WHERE terminal_id IN (SELECT terminal_id FROM dashboard.dummy)
) 
WHERE terminal_id IN (  
    SELECT terminal_id 
    FROM dashboard.down_event 
    WHERE terminal_id IN (SELECT terminal_id FROM dashboard.dummy)
) 
AND availability_date IN (
    SELECT down_date 
    FROM dashboard.down_event 
    WHERE down_date IN ( SELECT availability_date FROM dashboard.dummy)
)
```

If you need  a value   for each terminal then you need  a group by for terminal and join the subquery

```
UPDATE dashboard.dummy 
SET duration_sec = 3600 - t.my_duration
FROM (  
    SELECT terminal_id , min(down_duration_sec)  my_duration
    FROM dashboard.down_event 
    WHERE terminal_id IN (SELECT terminal_id FROM dashboard.dummy)
    GROUP BY terminal_id
) t 
WHERE t.terminal_id = dashboard.dummy.terminal_id
AND availability_date IN (
    SELECT down_date 
    FROM dashboard.down_event 
    WHERE down_date IN ( SELECT availability_date FROM dashboard.dummy)
)
```

and for distinct values you should use  DISTINCT clause

```
     UPDATE dashboard.dummy 
     SET duration_sec = 3600 - t.down_duration_sec 
     FROM ( 
        SELECT DISTINCT down_duration_sec, down_date, terminal_id 
        FROM dashboard.down_event 
        WHERE terminal_id IN (SELECT terminal_id FROM dashboard.dummy) 
     ) t 
     WHERE t.terminal_id = dashboard.dummy.terminal_id 
     AND dashboard.dummy.availability_date = t.down_date
```

Comment: But i need to update more than 1k data for these. The picture provided are for only 1 terminal. The actual data has more than 1k terminal. Can it update over 1k terminal?

Comment: your comment is not clear to me  ..  the where condition is not changed ..  so the code in my answer   update   the same number of rows as in your original code ..  the use of limit or aggregational function just return one  row only for the set  clause  ....  because you can't assign to a set clause more then a value ..

Comment: The problem is each terminal_id has different down_duration_sec that's why i'm subtracting them in 3600. The code: duration_sec = 3600 - ( SELECT min(down_duration_sec) FROM dashboard.down_event WHERE terminal_id IN (SELECT terminal_id FROM dashboard.dummy) ) Only subtract 1 column for all terminal

Comment: answer  updated ..  with a suggestion for each terminal values

Comment: Tried it but an error showed: 

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ON"
LINE 8: ) t ON t.terminal_id = dashboard.dummy.terminal_id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211994/discussion-between-elijah-leis-and-scaisedge).

Comment: @ElijahLeis  what's the (new) problem ??

Comment: HI in the query you have provided. Can i use these?

UPDATE dashboard.dummy
SET duration_sec = 3600 - t.down_duration_sec
FROM (
SELECT down_duration_sec, down_date, terminal_id
FROM dashboard.down_event
WHERE terminal_id IN (SELECT terminal_id FROM dashboard.dummy)
GROUP BY down_duration_sec, down_date, terminal_id
) t
WHERE t.terminal_id = dashboard.dummy.terminal_id
AND dashboard.dummy.availability_date = t.down_date

Comment: for get unique result you should use DISTINCT  answer  updated ..